# How does Raven know what collection to include?

Tags: c#, linq, indexing, ravendb

I am looking at the following sample code to include referenced documents and avoid round trip.

```
var order = session.Query<Order>()
   .Customize(x => x.Include<Order>(o=>o.CustomerId)) // Load also the costumer
   .First();
var customer = session.Load<Customer>(order.CustomerId);
```

My question is how does Raven know that this `o=>o.CustomerId` implies `Customer` document/collection? At no time was the entity `Customer` supplied in the query to get the `Order` entity. Yet Raven claims that the 2nd query to get `Customer` can be done against the cache, w/o any network trip.

If it's by naming convention, which seems like a very poor/fragile/brittle convention to adopt, what happens when I need to include more than 1 documents?

Eg. a car was purchased under 2 names, so I want to link back to 2 customers, the primary and secondary customer/driver. They're both stored in the Customer collection.

```
var sale = session.Query<Sale>()
   .Customize(x => x.Include<Sale>(o=>o.PrimaryCustomerId).Include<Sale>(o=>o.SecondaryCustomerId)) // Load also the costumer
   .First();
var primaryCustomer = session.Load<Customer>(order.PrimaryCustomerId);
var secondaryCustomer = session.Load<Customer>(order.SecondaryCustomerId);
```

How can I do the above in 1 network trip? How would Raven even knows that this `o=>o.PrimaryCustomerId` and `o=>o.SecondaryCustomerId` are references to the one and same table `Customer` since obviously the property name and collection name don't line up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raven doesn't have the concept of "tables".  It does know about "collections", but they are just a convenience mechanism.  Behind the scenes, all documents are stored in one big database.  The only thing that makes a "collection" is that each document has a `Raven-Entity-Name` metadata value.

Both the examples you showed will result in one round trip (each).  Your code looks just fine to me.

> My question is how does Raven know that this `o=>o.CustomerId` implies Customer document/collection? At no time was the entity Customer supplied in the query to get the Order entity.

It doesn't need to be supplied in the query.  As long as the data stored in the `CustomerId` field of the `Sale` document is a full document key, then that document will be returned to the client and loaded into session.

> Yet Raven claims that the 2nd query to get Customer can be done against the cache, w/o any network trip.

That's correct.  The session container tracks all documents returned - not just the ones from the query results.  So later when you call `session.Load` using the same document key, it already has it in session so it doesn't need to go back to the server.

Regardless of whether you query, load, or include - the document doesn't get deserialized into a static type until you pull it out of the session.  That's why you specify the `Customer` type in the `session.Load<Customer>` call.

> If it's by naming convention, which seems like a very poor/fragile/brittle convention to adopt ...

Nope, it's by the *value* stored in the property which is a document key such as `"customers/123"`.  Every document is addressable by its document key, with or without knowing the static type of the class.

> what happens when I need to include more than 1 documents?

The exact same thing.  There isn't a limit on how many documents can be included or loaded into session.  However, you should be sure to open the session in a `using` statement so it is disposed properly.  The session is a "Unit of Work container".

> How would Raven even knows that this `o=>o.PrimaryCustomerId` and `o=>o.SecondaryCustomerId` are references to the one and same table Customer since obviously the property name and collection name don't line up?

Again, it doesn't matter what the names of the fields are.  It matters that the data in those fields contains a document id, such as `"customers/123"`.  If you aren't storing the full string identifier, then you will need to build the document key inside the lambda expression.  In other words, if `Sale.CustomerId` contains just the number `123`, then you would need to include it with `.Include<Sale>(o=> "customers/" + o.CustomerId)`.

Comment: Matt, how does that work with Guid Ids? The example you've shown are string with sequential Ids. A Guid will not have the entity name, so how does Raven then resolve the correct collection to query? Or will it just query everything based on the Guid?

Comment: If you use a string for your `Id`, you have full control of the document key.  If you use an integer or Guid, then the string document key is created for you using the `FindFullDocumentKeyFromNonStringIdentifier` convention, which by default prepends a pluralized form of the type and a slash.  You can read more about non-string identifiers [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/basic-operations/loading-editing-existing-document#non-string-identifier).

Comment: In other words, the "document key" is *related* to the `Id`, but not necessarily exactly the same thing.  You wouldn't have a document key of just `"123"`.  It would have to be `"customers/123"`. And the same goes for guids.